# Putting attribute back into a request in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request, command

I'm having trouble putting an attribute back into a request in java.
Basically I have a jsp that gets an 'id' from the link to that page:

```
Integer prodId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("productId"));
```

Then in my command (I'm using the command pattern) I get the 'id' from the request and then return to the same jsp page but then the 'id' is no longer in the request and I get a number format exception

I have tried:

```
request.setAttribute("prodId", id);
```

but to no avail

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: why are you using 2 different keys?

Comment: When exactly are you getting the number format exception? In the JSP before the page loads, or on a subsequent request to that action?

Comment: It's just the way they were named, it's still the same value

Comment: Yes in the jsp before the page loads

Comment: `Parameter != Attribute` and `productId != prodId`

Answer (score 1):

Request Attribute and Request Parameters are different things.

1.Try retrieving it as :

```
request.getAttribute("prodId");
```

from your JSP, once you set the request attribute in command class, as

```
request.setAttribute("prodId", id);
```

This code gets the request parameter, not request attribute.

```
request.getParameter("productId");
```

2.Or, if you are forwarding to the JSP page from the Command class :

```
//this will let you use request.getParameter() in JSP.  
request.getRequestDispatcher(jspFilePath).forward(request,response);
```

Comment: I can retrieve it ok from the jsp, the problem is just putting it back so it is there when i return to that page

Comment: You don't take out anything from the request, you read it , whenever you are forwarding it to any page , forward the request as well so you can read the value from request . You can persist it in Session as well so that it is accessible throughout the session.

Comment: I know what your saying but the jsp page display a specific product based on the id that is passed along with the link to that page. So when I return to that page from the command class it can't get the id as I'm not going through the link to that page